# Can equivalent abelian categories have non-equivalent derived categories?

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, derived-categories

This is a point of stupid confusion for me.

Let $s:\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{B}$ be an equivalence of abelian categories. Does this functor induce a triangulated equivalence $\overline{s}: \mathbb{D}^b(\mathcal{A})\to \mathbb{D}^b(\mathcal{B})$ of bounded derived categories?

My intuition says that this is not true in general, since it is possible that for some $i$,  $\mathrm{Ext}^i_{\mathcal{A}}(A,B)$ and $\mathrm{Ext}^i_{\mathcal{B}}(s(A),s(B))$ are not isomorphic. As I understand, it then follows that $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{D}^b(\mathcal{A})}(A,B[i])$ and $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{D}^b(\mathcal{B})}(s(A),s(B)[i])$ are not the same. This would mean the derived categories are not equivalent right?

On the other hand it doesn't feels right that the derived category not respect equivalence. Is the remedy that I should be thinking about exact equivalences of abelian categories?

Comment: Everything used to define the derived category is preserved under equivalence of categories, so the derived categories are also equivalent. I don't see how it is possible that some Ext groups are different – whatever resolution you choose in one category is sent to a resolution in the other category, etc.

Comment: Take as an example the categories of finite dimensional representations of a discrete group G and its pro-algebraic completion G^alg (the tannakian dual of the category of finite dim G-reps). These abelian categories are by definition equivalent. However cohomology with coefficients in a given representation can be different. The connection to ext is that H^i(G,V) = Ext^i(k,V), where k is the trivial G-representation.

Comment: @PatrickElliott I agree with Zhen Lin. If $s:\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{B}$ is an equivalence, then $s$ induces an equivalence $D(\mathcal{A})\to D(\mathcal{B})$ and $s$ preserve Exts : $\operatorname{Ext}^i_{\mathcal{A}}(A,B)=\operatorname{Ext}^i_{\mathcal{B}}(s(A),s(B))$. In fact, if $B\to I^\bullet$ is an injective resolution of $B$, then $s(B)\to s(I^\bullet)$ is an injective resolution of $s(B)$.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with representations of pro-algebraic groups, but I suspect that you're computing its cohomology in some larger category than the category $\mathcal{B}$ of finite dimensional representations (the category $\mathcal{C}$ of rational representations, perhaps?). So your derived category would be $\mathbb{D}^b_\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{C})$, whose objects are complexes over $\mathcal{C}$ with cohomology in $\mathcal{B}$, rather than $\mathbb{D}^b(\mathcal{B})$. There are analogous situations where these are equivalent, but it's not automatic.

Comment: @Roland This is where I'm confused. There are known to be groups G and G-representations V such that the induced morphism H^i(G^alg,V)-> H^i(G,V) is not an isomorphism for any i>0. However the categories of G^alg-representations and G-representations are equivalent by definition

Comment: @PatrickElliott Although the category of finite dimensional representations of a group does constitute an abelian category, it is too usually small for the purposes of computing cohomology. For instance, you may not have projective/injective resolutions. Although the (bounded) derived category is defined for any abelian category whatsoever, it may give you derived functors that are different from those defined traditionally using resolutions etc.

Comment: @JeremyRickard I'm pretty sure I'm comporting the category of finite dimensional G representations and the category of finite dimensional rational G^alg modules. The whole reason I know the categories to be equivalent is that G^alg is the Tannakian dual of the category of finite dimensional G-representations.

Comment: @ZhenLin I agree that I'm am in the situation where injective resolutions will not be a computational tool. Perhaps I'm wrong that cohomology of G^alg representations is given by Yoneda extensions of the trivial representation?

Comment: It all depends on your definitions! How did you define cohomology? How did you define Yoneda extensions? If either one of these refers to possibly infinite-dimensional representations then there's your problem. Even if both are defined using only finite-dimensional representations, the proof that they are the same might make use of infinite-dimensional representations. This is one of the subtleties of defining things in terms of the whole entire category – you end up with a notion that, a priori, could be different when you enlarge or shrink the category.

Comment: To give an example of how @ZhenLin's last comment might apply here, suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional rational $G^\text{alg}$ representations, and $0\to W\to X\to Y\to V\to0$ is an extension where $X$ and $Y$ are infinite dimensional rational representations. Then this represents an element of $\text{Ext}^2(V,W)$, calculated in the category of all rational representations. But unless it is equivalent to an extension where $X$ and $Y$ are finite dimensional, it might not represent an element of $\text{Ext}^2$ calculated in the category of finite dimensional representations.

Comment: @ZhenLin Ok I define its cohomology for a pro-algebraic group G in a finite dimensional representation V as Ext^i_k[G](k, V), where k[G] is the hopf algebra associated with G, and we is thought of as a finite dimensional k[G] comodule. I believe this agrees with the so-called Hochschild cohomology of G as an affine group scheme used in SGA3, Part 1.